# Verify left singular vectors of A and A AT in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, svd

I had a linear algebra assignment on showing the relation between the left singular vectors of mxn matrix `A` and that of mxm `A@A.T`. By plugging in `A = U S VT` we can prove that `A@A.T = U S**2 U.T`, meaning that the left singular vectors of `A@A.T` are the same as those of `A`. However I can not verify it in numpy.

Here is the code I had

```py
m, n = 100, 85
for _ in range(10):
  A = np.random.randint(0, 100, (m, n))
  AAT = A @ A.T
  u, *_ = np.linalg.svd(A)
  u2, *_ = np.linalg.svd(AAT)
  assert np.allclose(np.abs(u), np.abs(u2))
```

Yet I can not pass the assert test. I am aware that SVD is not unique but I wonder what is the best way to verify the result.

Comment: You should use matplotlib to plot a heat map of the difference between them.  The two arrays are the same through column 85.  They differ after column 85.  I can't tell you what that means, but it must be significant.

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts. I rewatched the lecture and I think I got it now. The first `rank(A)` columns are equal under absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last n - m columns of U form a basis of the nullspace of A^T. A^T has the same nullspace as AA^T, so the last n - m columns of U_2 form a basis of the same space. Maybe there's a better way to show this, but here's one:

```
>>> np.linalg.matrix_rank(np.hstack((u[:, n:], u2[:, n:])), 1e-10)
15 # m - n
```

Those last columns don't need to be any particular basis vectors as long as they span the correct space, so one shouldn't expect them to be equal.

Comment: I see, it's clever!